# Does it matter where code is placed in .HTACCESS?

Tags: .htaccess

in htaccess, i have (i.e. Wordpress has)  rewrite rules like this:

```
.........
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
..........
```

i want to insert directives in `.htaccess`, like these:

```
ExpiresByType image/jpg   "access plus 1 year"
Header unset ETag
Header unset Last-Modified
 ...............
```

does it matter if I place them before or after the the first block?

Comment: have a look at [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/213191/does-is-matter-in-what-order-rules-are-placed-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

In your case it does not. The rewrite base rules are for permalink. The directives you are related cache-control. As a personal choice I would add those after rewrite base rule. Test your website via:

http://www.gtmetrix.com to check whether your entries are making an effect.

To add further:

These directives have a cascading effect somewhat similar to cascading style sheet. So if two directives on the same feature are added in a single .htaccess file, the later one will get precedence.

I recommend the following links :

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html
- https://gtmetrix.com/leverage-browser-caching.html

Hope this answer the question.

Comment: Could you say _why_ the order does not matter in this case?

Comment: The link you have posted (`gtmetix`) looks very spammy/malicious - multiple redirections?!

Comment: it does not matter as the directives are for two different topics. Please go through my links for further details

Comment: @w3dk there should be `gtmetrix`, not `gtmetix`.